# Facebook audience network ads crash from ads.db android

Tags: android, admob, ads, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

I'm getting the below crash reporting in firebase crash reporting console. Its looking like, its from facebook ads. Please give a solution for this crash.

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:304)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:355)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:222)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/databases/ads.db
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference (SQLiteClosable.java:55)
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction (SQLiteDatabase.java:520)
    com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$2.a ()
    com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$2.b ()
    com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$1.a ()
    com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d$1.doInBackground ()
    android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:292)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Please let me know the reason before hitting the down vote..

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug from Facebook side. They already confirmed it.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/213725762497306/